# BaseX close Spring Boot classloader

Tags: java, basex

I have a Spring Boot (2.7.5) with BaseX 10.3

On start up I have a server component starting the server in a @PostConstruct

```
System.setProperty("org.basex.path", basexDataPath);
Context c = new Context();
c.soptions.set(StaticOptions.DBPATH, basexDataPath);
this.server = new BaseXServer(c,sl.finish());
```

And a client component creating a session in also a @PostConstruct

```
ClientSession clientSession = new ClientSession(basexServerHost, basexServerPort, UserText.ADMIN, basexAdminPassword);
```

And then I load functx (still in postconstruct) :

```
RepoInstall ri = new RepoInstall(tmpLib.getAbsolutePath(),null);//tmpLib = functx file
clientSession.execute(ri);
```

In Eclipse it works but when packaged and running from the jar, the application fail to start because I get a ClassNotFoundException of my own class.

I figured out, that it can not find the class because the classloader is closed.
And **Basex is closing it** :

Here is the stack :

[image: closing stack trace]

What is wrong with my implementation ? How can I avoid BaseX to close the classloader ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The BaseX ModuleLoader used to close URLClassLoaders, assuming that it had instantiated them itself for module loading:

```java
      if(loader instanceof URLClassLoader) {
      try {
        ((URLClassLoader) loader).close();
      } catch(final IOException ex) {
```

But this could also affect the default classloader, in case it was an URLClassLoader, so it was fixed recently ([b82b4c](https://github.com/BaseXdb/basex/commit/b82b4cdfb0f78b5ce3418f07461427095abb7449)). The fix is not yet contained in a released version, though.

Comment: Thanks, Gunther. I'm glad to report a new stable snapshot is available now: https://files.basex.org/releases/latest/

Comment: Thank switching to the 10.5-SNAPSHOT fixed the issue !